# jquery mobile function return unidentified from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, function, mobile

I'm trying to use this function to return the name of an exercise when I give him the ex_id, but it just returns undefined.

```
function getExerciseName(ex_id){
        $.getJSON('db.json', function(data_ex) {
            for (var i in data_ex.exercises) {
                if(data_ex.exercises[i].id == ex_id)
                {
                    return data_ex.exercises[i].name;        
                } else { 
                    return 'failure'
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The ex_id is correct, I can't seem to find anything wrong with this.

I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: What is the actual JSON string being returned?

Comment: It's returning "failure" as I can check on firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you expect to get the return value? `getExerciseName` calls `$.getJSON` with a target and a callback and then it returns `undefined` since you've not defined a return statement.

The callback will be called at some later time and its return value is lost since it's not handled.

I think you need to read up on asyncronous functions.

An option is to return the result of the actual $.getJSON call which will be a promise and then do something with that or pass along a callback to deal with the return values into the function call

EDIT: 
Actually there's another bug in the code as well. The if clause will make the for loop break after the first element regardless if it's the right one or not. I expect you want the code to only return false if the test is not true for any element in the returned array?

try something like this instead:

```
function getExerciseName(ex_id, callback){
   $.getJSON('db.json', function(data_ex) {
      for (var i in data_ex.exercises) {
         if(data_ex.exercises[i].id == ex_id) {
            return callback(data_ex.exercises[i].name);        
         }
      }
      callback('failure');
   });
}

// and call it with something like this
getExerciseName(2, function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: Well, what seems to be odd is that the return appears 'unidentified' on the page, but the console output seems to be correct.

Comment: Which return? I left the return in the if-clause only to break out of the for loop. At no point is anything relevant actually returned. The return statement _only_ returns from the anonymous inner function, it doesn't return from getExerciseName

Comment: Think of callback functions as telling the computer what to do once it comes back with an answer. The computer doesn't stop and wait for the answer it just memorises what it should do when it gets it. So getExerciseName sends a call to the api and says when you're done with that, do this with the result. Then it goes on and sees it's got nothing else to do and returns undefined. At some point later an answer comes back and the computer calls the callback with the answer

Comment: I was referring to the return of the function when called on the page. The console shows the values that I am looking for, but the page does not show the same as the console, how can this be?

Comment: If you're using my example code then note that I put a callback-function in the call that will be called with the result in the anonymous function in the if-clause in the code above and in that callback I call `console.log` with the result which will log the data to the console. The actual call of the getExerciseName-function will return undefined so that kind of depends on how you're using the function

Comment: I tried the following `getExerciseName(2, function(data) { ex_name=data; });` and then tried to write the ex_name variable expecting it to write the name and it does not work. Why is it so?

Comment: You really need to read up on what asynchronous/non-blocking means. the function(data) {ex_name=data; } won't be called until after the result returns from the ajax call BUT the program doesn't stop and wait for it so the anonymous function hasn't been called when the next line of the code executes. I can't explain it clearer than that so I suggest you read up on callbacks... possibly start here http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Comment: Hmm.. The callback is only called after the function is complete, but since it's ajax, it will not stop, so the callback won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getExerciseName` does not return anything. It calls a function `$.getJSON` that has a callback function. The callback function is called at the end of `getJSON` but asynchronously. There is no way you return a synchronous result from within an asynchronous function.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
function getExerciseName(ex_id){
        $.getJSON('db.json', function(data_ex) {
            for (var i in data_ex.exercises) {
                if(data_ex.exercises[i].id == ex_id)
                {
                    return dosomethingWithExerciseName(data_ex.exercises[i].name);
                }
            }
            alert("failure");
        });
    }
```

It is your only way out of the asynchronous callback function I am afraid.

EDIT: changing the return value

Comment: Hmm, I see. I am learning javascript and jquery as I am trying to develop something.. And these terms in english become harder for me to understand, as it's not my main language. How can I get around this problem? And learn more about what synchronous and asunchronous functions are?

Comment: To understand why there is no other option, you need to think of a callback function as something that will be called at some point in the future. It is not called within the thread of `getExerciseName` that finishes right after `getJSON` is launched. It could take time for the `JSON` to arrive so javascript uses asynchronous calls. Think of it as two different threads really.

Comment: The main problem for you is that you do not return anything, no matter what synchronous and asynchronous are. Since getJSON does not return the result of the function you define, you cannot extract value from there, the return value of your inner function is lost. You need to find another way to get the information out (cf my proposition)

Comment: I tried your proposition, created a function that received the exercise name and stored it into a variable, but still only got the alert. It looks like it's failing at the if comparison possibly? That would be odd since I've used the same for and if before and had no problems, and am sure that the comparison with the ex_id does exist within the db.json exercise.id

Comment: You probably want to take the else out of the for loop

Comment: You can see it in my edit (which is not equivalent to your initial code either).

Comment: Your code does write to the variable correctly as it shows on the console the value that I wanted. but the return function that handles the exercise name into a variable that I have created, when I use the variable on the page it still shows as unidentified. Why does this happen?

Comment: You never return a value (`return` is just here to stop the execution once you've found a match). The only place you will find the exercise name is within `dosomethingWithExerciseName`. You need to write your code based on this assumption.